# Data structur similar to Array

Tags: arrays, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I need a data structure that has O (1) access time like an array, but where you don't have to know the size beforehand. A linked list is out because of the access time and otherwise I only read from a dynamic array. But my professor doesn't want me to use a dynamic array. What else is there?

Thanks for any help!

Lisa

Comment: why don't we use arraylist?

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use dynamic arrays? Like you don’t use all entries, you don’t simply append, and you can’t use time for initialising what you don’t use? Dynamic arrays are the right tool for the job in most cases, so there must be a reason to exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Hash tables - Read, Search, Insertion, and Deletion yields O(1) each.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, that a Hash Table is pretty difficult in my case. But thank you!